# Should Ubuntu related code samples and sniplets be prefixed with sudo iff necessary?

Tags: discussion

As usage of `sudo` is state of the art in Ubuntu to gain privileges and implied and obligatory in the default setup. Should code samples and sniplets in answers be prefixed with `sudo` if the command requires root privileges although the necessity of privileges is clear from the context (e.g. `apt-get` almost always needs privileges and I see sudo omitted in a lot of answers)? Are edits which add `sudo` in such a situation welcome?

Pro for adding `sudo` (iff necessary):

- code becomes copy-pastable line by line

Cons:

- answers are not compatible with changes to the authentication (if in 2192 Ubuntu no longer works with `sudo`, but another mechanism

A simpler form of the question: Should answers not prefixed with `sudo` which don't include a hint about necessary privileges (be it in the text, with `#` as prompt or however) and **contain code which wouldn't work if typed into a terminal** with copy-paste (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/436424/173287) be edited generally?

Comment: In that specific answer, every command needs to be run as root. At which point, few people will bother with `sudo` on every command.

Comment: The problem with not mentioning sudo is that you almost always get the reply _"I tried it but got Access Denied?!"_

Comment: Screw all this. We should start using `pkexec`.

Answer (score 3):

If `sudo` is necessary.

I do use `sudo` for a single command. However, if you need to run a series of commands as root, I would just specify that "the below commands need to be run as root."

`sudo` is dangerous. It's best to not use it unless necessary (or you know how to not destroy a system).

Answer (score 0):

### NO!

There are very many cases where using `sudo` is either unnecessary or actively harmful and should be avoided. It is, unfortunately, characteristic of new users to just slap a `sudo` onto any command. This can often lead to issues (for example when copying files) and should not be encouraged.

Using `sudo` is not "state of the art". It is a tool that should only be used in specific instances and should never be used lightly. Admittedly, the specific question you link to does contain commands that need to be run as root. Note, however, that with the exception of the two `apt-get` commands, the OP has used `#` as the symbol for the prompt which is *nixspeak for a root terminal.

So, sure, if the commands really *need* to be run as root and the OP does not specify this, you could edit it. But you should always be very careful to *only* do so if `sudo` is absolutely necessary and not "just in case".

Comment: I edited the initial formulation of the question. It was confusing. I stated "if the command requires root privileges", though (as far as I'm concerned this is a yes/no question - if I'm mistaken there, please help me understand with a comment to the question). The idea was not to add `sudo` to every command in a snipplet - that's ridiculous, I agree. Good point with the `#`, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @KarlRichter I realize, it's just that I've seen too many answers here using `sudo` when it's not needed. Since it is never dangerous to leave it and it can be dangerous to use it when not needed, I wouldn't recommend blanket edits. They should be done only when the editor knows what they're doing.

Comment: In my understanding your answer implies that unnecessary `sudo` should be removed from answers (that's why I added logical _iff_ as in _if and only if_ to the title).